# In Karate DSL, is there a way to define custom keywords for 'Given' step

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I am working on a Karate DSL project. I have 2 dependent ( A and B) SOAP transactions that I am testing. The 1st transaction namely A needs to be completed before my 2nd transaction B. I am able to accomplish this by calling the A's feature file from B.

My current code looks like this :

```
Background:
* url = https://www.abcshgda.com/service
* def result = call read(A.feature)

Scenario: B needs to run once the prerequisite A is completed.

Given request read(B_req.xml)
When soap action ''
Then status 200
```

But what I really want to do is something like this :

```
Given A
When SOAP ''
Then status 200
```

Since Karate is DSL, is there a way I can do the above without actually using the     predefined keyword request and reading the request XML. Instead have A do that in the background.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a deliberate design decision, if you want more details, read this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/398

Karate seems to be working fine for you already and my opinion is you are un-necessarily trying to make it "look more readable" but you really won't gain anything from this from my experience.

The best you can do is this, if you have defined a JS function (or Java utility) that takes care of doing "A":

```
Given myJsFunctionThatCallsA()
And request read('B_req.xml')
When soap action ''
Then status 200
```